# When using boost::asio LNK 2001 (Release)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, boost, boost-asio

I'm developing chat server (name is PengChat) and it is main source code.

(`CServerSocket.h` is included `boost/asio.hpp`) and there are two errors.

```
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::system::system_category(void)" (?system_category@system@boost@@YAABVerror_category@12@XZ) 
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::system::generic_category(void)" (?generic_category@system@boost@@YAABVerror_category@12@XZ)
```

My environment is

- OS - Windows 8 Pro K (I'm Korean)
- IDE - Visual Studio 2012
- Properties → Code Generator → Runtime Library - Multi Thread (`/MT`) (in release)

Do you know about these errors?

Please help me.

Thanks.

PS. In debug mode (using `/MTd` option). it is compiled well. but in release mode (using `/MT` option), there are two errors.

PS2. I can't use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, it is strange; please look comment window

**EDIT**

Source code for application is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory>
#include "../PengChatServerLib/CServerSocket.h"

#ifdef _MSC_VER
    #ifdef _DEBUG
        #pragma comment(lib, "../Debug/PengChatServerLib") 
    #else
        #pragma comment(lib, "../Release/PengChatServerLib")
    #endif
#endif

int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service iosrv;

    std::unique_ptr<PengChat::CServerSocket> pSock(new PengChat::CServerSocket(iosrv, 8888)); 

    getchar();

    pSock.reset();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: oh no, my source code is missing. here is a source code.  #include <stdio.h>
#include <memory>

#include "../PengChatServerLib/CServerSocket.h"

#ifdef _MSC_VER
#ifdef _DEBUG
#pragma comment(lib, "../Debug/PengChatServerLib")
#else
#pragma comment(lib, "../Release/PengChatServerLib")
#endif
#endif

int main()
{
 boost::asio::io_service iosrv;

 std::unique_ptr<PengChat::CServerSocket> pSock(new PengChat::CServerSocket(iosrv, 8888));
 getchar();
 pSock.reset();

 return 0;
}

Comment: Please edit your source code into your question - we can't really read it in the comments!

Comment: @Chowlett I can't do it.. what is wrong..?

Comment: @BombPenguin: I have edited your source code into your question; once the edit has been approved it should be visible.

Comment: You should link with `Boost.System` (libboost_system*.lib). Make sure that the library exists, and the linker path is ok.